# Use Launchpad while downloading from AppStore

Tags: mac-appstore, launchpad

I am just getting set up with my first mac. The current annoyance is that I am downloading xcode from AppStore (2.5 GB!!), and every app in the Launchpad is hidden - there is just the downloading progress of xcode.

Do I really have to wait an hour while the download finishes, until I can launch anything not already in the dock?? I cant believe that!

(OSX Yosemite)

Comment: I found out what was happening. The launcher page was full, so it just took a new page to show the downloading app. I only realised this after the download completed, as I thought the download had put launcher into a locked state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Launchpad will not run for any reason, you can access many of your Applications via the Finder. In the Finder, press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, or go to the **Go** menu and select **Applications**.

Answer (score 3):

You can open Finder and go to your Applications folder to access all your apps.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use Spotlight to find an app and launch it.